# Let $f$ be a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)f''(x)\leq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the derivative $f'(x)$ and all its successive derivatives exist everywhere and also $f(x)f''(x)\leq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two consecutive roots of $f(x)=0$.
Prove that $f'''(\gamma)=0$ for some $\gamma \in(\alpha,\beta)$

I feel that the problem may not be true

I have been able to draw the curve of such a function..

[image]

Comment: You have constructed a counterexample only for interval $[\alpha, \beta]$. It appears that we can have such counterexamples if interval of definition of $f$ is finite and closed. But for $f$ defined on whole of $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)f''(x)\leq 0$ the result is true.

Comment: this can be useful $f''(c)>0$ the function is convex, if $f''(c)<0$ the function is concave